# bootstrap website to wide on IOS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some trouble on this and can not figure it out on my own. I am not any kind of coder just dabbled in it a few times starting in 1998. I am trying to design a website for a friend of mine using bootstrap 3.3.4 for the first time. After getting it online I realized it is way to wide on Iphones. It shows about 50% padding on the right side. You have to zoom in to use view the website correctly. Can anybody give me any input on what can be causing this? I cant find a cause anywhere. On the desktop version it works perfectly even when I resize the window. It is a little to wide on android also but is not near as noticeable as it is on IOS.  The website is up at

[This link](http://www.precisiontreeandlandscaping.com)

Thank you for any help

Comment: For a start, Bootstrap requires jQuery which you appear to be missing.

Comment: Actually, let me clarify that more. You are loading Boostrap js in the head, then loading jQuery and Bootstrap js again at the bottom. Remove the one from head.

Comment: iPhone 4S / iOS8 - looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell exactly what is wrong as I don't have an iPhone. But some observations:

1. You are loading Boostrap javasript in the `head`, then loading jQuery and Bootstrap js again at the bottom. Remove the one from `head`as it's giving a console error.
2. In the footer, your `row` has as it's child element a class of `col-me-6` which I suspect is a typo. Also it has an inline style of `width: 100%` which is not advisable - use the grid system to control widths.
3. Finally, and most likely your problem, in the `#portfolio` container, your first `row` has some invalid contents. Only a `col-*` can be a child of a `row`. You also have a nested `row` which is screwing up the margins and giving you the extra wide window.

Comment: Thank you for that. That 3rd one got it fixed. Also I know it looks like a complete mess so thanks everyone for not knocking it.